# slf4j not logging on a Cloud Endpoints AppEngine application

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, slf4j

I am using Google Cloud Endpoints in AppEngine Standard Environment Java 8. I am building using Maven.

I am trying to use slf4j for logging, but nothing is logged at any level (logs do not appear in Stackdriver Logging). I have included both slf4j and slf4j-jdk14 binding in my `pom.xml`.

Logging using `java.util.logging` works as expected, with log appearing in Stackdriver Logging according to the log level I set in my `logging.properties`. But I would prefer using the slf4j interface.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the endpoints framework depends on `slf4j-nop.jar`.

This can be seen by running `mvn dependency:tree`. You can then see the nop jar in the `/WEB-INF/lib/`.

To avoid including the jar in the war, use the packaging excludes option of the `maven-war-plugin`, e.g.:

```
   <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.6</version>
      <configuration>
         <webResources>
            <resource>
               <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
               <filtering>true</filtering>
               <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
            </resource>
         </webResources>
         <packagingExcludes>
             WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-nop-*.jar
         </packagingExcludes>
      </configuration>
   </plugin>
```

Also make sure you include a dependency on the binding you want to use, e.g.

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
     <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
     <version>1.7.25</version>
 </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have opened a ticket for this with the Google Endpoints team, but there is ongoing discussion on if and how it will be resolved.

https://github.com/cloudendpoints/endpoints-java/issues/116

In the meantime, you can also exclude slf4j-nop like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.endpoints</groupId>
    <artifactId>endpoints-framework</artifactId>
    <version>${endpoints-framework.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-nop</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```